# Django : Error 'str' object has no attribute 'get' when populating model with csv file

Tags: django, file, error-handling

I'm trying to populate a model with an csv file like this :

```
if form.is_valid():
        #form.save()
        print("form1 valid")
        csvfile = request.FILES['myfilebase']
        print(csvfile)
        try: 
            f=open(csvfile,"rt")
            #print(csvfile)
            my_data = csv.reader(f)
            for row in my_data:
                print(row)
        except:
            msg = "Cannot open file - is it CSV?"
            print("not opened")
            return msg

    else:
        print("not valide form")
```

but I'm getting this error :

> 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

this problem is in the `csvfile` variable , because when I replace `csvfile` with the full path, my code works perfectly. I guess I'm missing something when get the file name from my `FileField`
Edit here is my view :

```
def clientsBase(request):
    form = formFile(request.POST, request.FILES)
    #csvfile = request.POST['myfilebase']
    #print(csvfile)
    print("entrer en clientsBase")
    if form.is_valid():
        #form.save()
        print("form1 valid")
        csvfile = request.FILES['myfilebase']
        print(csvfile)
        try: 
            f=open(csvfile,"rt")
            #print(csvfile)
            my_data = csv.reader(f)
            for row in my_data:
                print(row)
        except:
            msg = "Cannot open file - is it CSV?"
            print("not opened")
            return msg

    else:
        print("not valide form")
    return redirect('/veentes/')
```

Any help how can I handle this error. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You don't show all the code, but presumably this is inside a view. A view always needs to return an HttpResponse; you are returning a string, msg.

Comment: I edited my question, I return a redirect('/veentes/')

Comment: But inside the `except` block you return msg.

Comment: now that I just print msg in excep. I got the error mesage that it cannot open the file. why it cant open it ?

Comment: Because `request.FILES['myfilebase']` is not a filename, it's an in-memory file. You should pass it directly to `csv.reader`, rather than calling open(). Also, you should *not* use a bare except statement; you should only catch the errors you know how to deal with.

Comment: I understand thank you , but even if I do so, I got the error iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?). I guess this happening when iterating on rows of the csvfile